# Set background color (not Text Color) of Back button in UINavigationBar IOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, back-button

Is there any way to set the background color of back button in NavigationBar like this

[image]

There are some post available on SO which shows how to set Tint color. But can anyone let me know if there is way to set **Background Color** like shown in image above. or i have to set in custom way?

Answer (score 2):

for navigationBar you should setbackgroundImage

```
            navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "your image name"),
 forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: The best answer, i've ever met.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `Tint color`, but I can not make it work properly.

I do that by adding an `UIView` at the back of the `UINavigationBar`. In that case it must be properly positioned using `Autolayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize, that is not actually back button background.
If you'll take a closer look at navigation bar, you will see back button has a limited width and height. Something like this:

[image]

So if you really need to customize your navigation bar, you have 2 variants:

1) set your navigation bar background image, with fixed or adapting back button background

2) implement custom navigation bar, ignoring system UINavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom image and set title manually

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customImage"]
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```